# Can I skip the jumpship sequences?

Tags: battletech

When travelling to another system there are always a number of cut-scenes showing the ship dock to the jumpship, travel trough space etcetera. Is there a way to permanently disable these?

Comment: I've founf no way myself but would love it if you could. Likewise Why does it always load up into the title video rather than going to the title screen - how many times does it think I want to watch the history of the battletech universe?

Comment: If you're interested in '*hacky*' methods, I wonder if shortening the travel times in the config files would let you set them to 0 (or close to 0) to enable insta-travel. The only downside to this method would be that no in-game time would pass (or be skipped), and so repair/upgrade jobs wouldn't progress as you travel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

you can press "esc" to skip the docking scene....but it does not work with the jump scene

Comment: Edits are done to improve the readability and clarity of your answer. Please don't roll them back.